# JSDoc, documenting functions stored inside an object

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

I'm having trouble getting functions to show in JSDoc when they are stored inside an object.  So I have something like:

```
/**
*/
var methods = {};

/**
Get all resources
*/
methods.getResources = function(){
  return name;
}
```

How would I have the getResources function show up in JSDoc?  I've tried adding `@class` to methods with no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`@namespace`](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-namespace.html) and [`@memberOf`](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-memberof.html) should be what you're looking for.

```js
/**
 * @namespace methods
 */
var methods = {};

/**
 * Get all resources
 * @memberOf methods
 */
methods.getResources = function(){
  return name;
}
```